# Задан словарь [Int: Double] Нужно через функцию вернуть словарь [Int: Int]. В новом словаре значения в /10 от заданных

Tags: swift, set

### Начинающий программист, буду благодарен за помощь
Задается словарь со значениями [Int: Double]
Через функцию возвращается словарь со значениями [Int: Int]
где key - неизменное значение, а значение value уменьшается в 10 раз от начально заданного
пробовал через словарь.values / 10 и присвоение всем значениям, но выдает ошибку
func food(set: [Int: Double]) -> [Int: Int] {
userPoints
var points = userPoints
var valuesArray = [points.values]
valuesArray.map { Int($0)/10 }
}
}
userPoints - инкапсулировал

func food(set: [Int: Double]) -> [Int: Int] {

```
userPoints
var points: [Int: Double] = userPoints
var valuesArray = [points.values]
var points2: [Int: Int] = points.mapValues(Int.init)
return points2
}
```

print(food.points2)

Сделал вот так, но застрял с выводом и распечаткой результата

Comment: Кроме описания кода, стоит привести сам код.

Comment: И ещё напишите, какую выдает ошибку.

Comment: func food(set: [Int: Double]) -> [Int: Int] {
    userPoints
    var points = userPoints
    var valuesArray = [points.values]
    valuesArray.map { Int($0)/10 }
    }

Comment: No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: Попробуйте еще отредактировать вопрос. Добавьте код только в текст вопроса, а не в заголовок. И ещё, что такое, отдельно стоящее слово "userPoints"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userPoints - закапсулированный словарь с типом данных [Int: Double]
Стояла задача перевести в [Int: Int], где новые values в 10 раз меньше старых

```
userPoints
func food(set: [Int: Double]) -> [Int: Int] {
    var points: [Int: Double] = userPoints
    var points2: [Int: Int] = userPoints.mapValues(Int.init)

    return points2.mapValues{$0 / 10}
    }
```

Comment: А для чего у вас третья строчка кода "var points: [Int: Double] = userPoints" ?

Comment: И ещё, чтобы не возникало вопросов, вы бы могли в своем изначальном вопросе (и в этом ответе) присвоить для userPoints какое-то значение. А так у вас это непонятное слово гуляет туда сюда.

Comment: И ещё один вопрос: зачем у вас функция принимает входное значение "set: [Int: Double]", если оно нигде внутри функции не используется?